# Slight changes to Harvard's agsm.bst

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, spanish

I've been writing my thesis and using bibtex, unfortunately I could not find a `.bst` to match the required format. It requires some particles to change from English to Spanish, as well as some changes in formatting. The most similar style I could find was Harvard's agsm.

1. Authors to be listed with "y" instead of "and".
2. Use "et al" in text when there are more than 3 authors.
3. Underline the title.
4. Place the year after the title.

This is shown here!

[image]

Can this please be done by modifying directly the `agsm.bst`? I've tried to use makebst but latex doesn't seem to be able to use the `.bst` produced by that.

My code is this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,letterpaper,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>.}}
\decimalpoint %\spanishdecimal{.}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[dcucite]{harvard}

\begin{document}
asdasd \cite{chsh_inequality} asdasd \cite{aspect_test_bell}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{ejem_biblio}

\end{document}
```

and my bib is

```
@ARTICLE{chsh_inequality,
   author = {{Clauser}, J.~F. and {Horne}, M.~A. and {Shimony}, A. and {Holt}, R.~A.
    },
    title = "{Proposed Experiment to Test Local Hidden-Variable Theories}",
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
     year = 1969,
    month = oct,
   volume = 23,
    pages = {880-884},
      doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.880},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1969PhRvL..23..880C},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{aspect_test_bell,
   author = {{Aspect}, A. and {Grangier}, P. and {Roger}, G.},
    title = "{Experimental Tests of Realistic Local Theories via Bell's Theorem}",
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
 keywords = {Fluorescence, phosphorescence},
     year = 1981,
    month = aug,
   volume = 47,
    pages = {460-463},
      doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.47.460},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981PhRvL..47..460A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem (what do you meant that the style produced with makebst does not work?)

Comment: for a first test put the new bst-file into your documents directory and change `\bibliographystyle{...}` to the new bst name.

Comment: If I use `\bibliographystyle{fiuady}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` I get

`The style file: fiuady.bst`

instead of

`The style file: agsm.bst
Database file #1: ejem_biblio.bib`

Comment: The result is a document in which there are question marks in citations, and there is no Bibliography

Comment: Please try to remove the auxiliary files (e.g., `.aux`) and try to run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` again.

Comment: @OscarLazo: did you also run `bibtex` on your file?

Comment: I erased the auxiliary files and did the commands mentioned by Guido, but got the same result with the .bst produced by makebst. Should I post that file?

Comment: @OscarLazo Your custom `.bst` should work after `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` (the standard 'recipe'), certainly if BibTeX is finding it. On your various cusomisation questions, the StackExchange model works best if questions apply to more than one person. Each customisation does, but asking them all in one go makes it very unlikely to apply to anyone else. You might want to see if the individual parts have been asked before.

Comment: I have ran again makebst and the new file worked, (I hadn't selected merlin at the begining of the questioning but spanish instead). I'll try to ask more specific questions.